# Addressing submit button (Python mechanize)

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

The website I am dealing with has more than one `"submit"` routine:

```
    <input type="submit" id="ctrl_submit_149" class="submit" value="" title="search">
    [...]
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="search">search</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="reset">reset</button>
```

By default, mechanize uses the first of these, but I want to address the search button. I have found a quick and dirty way to get this control (`br.form.controls[16]`), but how can I tell mechanize to use this one when submitting?